# Using jQuery tooltip at runtime by livequery

Tags: jquery, runtime, tooltip, livequery

Does anybody know how to use tooltip at runtime using livequery? I found some infos, but for me it doesnt work.

```
jQuery('.button').bind('click', function () {
    std();
});

function std () {
    jQuery('.abcd').livequery.run(function() {
        jQuery('.abcd').tooltip();
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide examples of what you have tried, and be a little clearer on what it is you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your code to mean this:

When `.button` is clicked you want to enable the tooltip functionality on all elements with class `.abcd`. If this is your intention simply use

```
jQuery('.button').bind('click', function () {
    std(); //activate tooltip support
});

function std () {
    //internal function is called once for every found/new .abcd element
    jQuery('.abcd').livequery(function() {
        $(this).tooltip();
    });
}
```

Note that probably should prevent `.button` from being clicked more than once as that could lead to unexpected sideeffects